# is there a difference in how android devices process depending on the manufacturer

Tags: android, bitmap, sony

Pretty much in the title. I'm guessing there are some differences in how data is processed and passed around the app. But is there anything drasticly different in how some makes do this?

The reason for the question being that I have an app (obv) and on the majority of phones it works great, with the occasional hiccup. I have noticed that on Sony models, it throws its toys out the pram and refuses to play ball.

It's a service (sticky) and the task it's doing is simply sending one image to a server, base64 encoded along with some extra text fields to a server. I'm getting a null exception when I do null checks on every value used. As I said, this tends to only really happen on Sony models.

Comment: Most manufacturers take the basic Android framework and expand on it, creating their own unique UI/UX. Some of those unique features cause the phones to differ a bit in exactly how they do things. For example, HTC can implement a quick restart which requires special permissions to receive boot broadcasts.

Comment: Thanks, so would these alterations to the framework affect would a service would run?

Comment: They very well could. If you are running into an issue with a certain manufacturer and it isn't error on your end it is very likely someone else has run into the same issue in the past. Search around a bit, I'm sure something will pop up.

Comment: ok, thanks for the info. I shall return to the depths of Google :)